# Function: Image in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to right a function that creates a JFrame that contains an image. Problem is I only get an empty JFrame (no errors). Is there a better way to do this?
Here is the class that contains the function:

```
public class Play extends JFrame 
{

    protected static ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Fadil\\Desktop\\Coding\\civii\\earth.jpg");
    protected static JLabel label = new JLabel(icon); 
    protected static JFrame f = new JFrame("Age Of")


    public static void PlayStart()  
    {
        f.getContentPane().add(label);
        f.repaint();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: You probably specified the path of the image incorrectly. Don't hardcode the path to a directory on your computer. Instead put the image is the save directory where your class file is and the just use the filename of the image.

Comment: Your design doesn't make much sense. Why do you extend `JFrame` if you are also having `static JFrame` field?

Comment: I have to admit that I didn't really know what extends does, up till you mentioned it :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply do the following 
1- create Panel class and use media tool kit to get image in your class path lie this 
class P extends JPanel {
      Image bg = null;

```
  P() {
    MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
    bg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("yourimage");
    mt.addImage(bg, 0);
    try {
      mt.waitForAll();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         int imwidth = bgimage.getWidth(null);
         int imheight = bgimage.getHeight(null);
         g.drawImage(bg, 1, 1, null);
  }
}
```

2- add the panel to your frame  to the frame

```
public class JF extendts JFrame{
    public JF(){
            add(new P()) ; 
            sitSize(300,200) ; 
    }
}
```

Comment: MediaTracker, really? Still using Java 1.3? Personally, better and easier to use ImageIO, at least it throws an IOException when the image can't be read for some reason...besides, what's wrong with using a JLabel?  Also, all Swing components implement ImageObserver and you should be passing it to getWidth/Height and drawImage, this will remove the need for MediaTracker